# Why is my computer randomly changing windows?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, youtube

Recently, my computer changes windows randomly. One moment I'm search on Chrome, then it switches to another app. I didn't pay attention, but I think it always changes to Chrome and not other apps. Even when  I'm using Chrome, it changes to another Chrome window. I've watched my computer without touching the keyboard and it just changes. Chrome also flashes orange on the taskbar for seemingly no reason, but I think (not sure) that it only happens when I'm on https://youtube.com.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by a bug or malware, perhaps you haven't updated Google Chrome?

#### Malware

When Using chrome, you might have downloaded something from an untrusted source, or you might have visited a site which has malware and it infected the browser/computer!

If you are on computer go to: `chrome://settings/reset` > `clean up computer` > `Check`

#### Bugs & Updates

Go to `chrome://settings/help` and check if chrome is up to date.

If the problem still continues here are other options:

1. Check for malware
2. Uninstall and reinstall chrome